# Why does this code only work in one instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, hotkeys, keypreview

I've set my form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

I've added this code:

```
private void PlatypusScheduleForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9)
  {
    tabControlPlatypi.SelectedTab = tabPageDuckBill;
  }
  else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
  {
    tabControlPlatypi.SelectedTab = tabPagePlatypus;
  }
}
```

When I mash <kbd>F10</kbd>, it works as expected; mashing <kbd>F9</kbd>, however, does nothing.

`tabPageDuckBill` is the design-time/default `tabPage` that displays. Why would <kbd>F10</kbd> work in taking me to the "other" tab page, but <kbd>F9</kbd> then not go back to the original?

Comment: Do you need to mash F10 to get it to work?  When you set a breakpoint in the method, does F9 cause it to fire?

Comment: Is something else previewing the keys and capturing F9?

Comment: Stepping through it when putting a breakpoint on the first line, it works; "live" (without the breakpoint), it doesn't...??? There is no reference in code to F9 anywhere else.

Comment: I've found the problem: I've got code in the TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged() event, which is messing things up.

Comment: ..and yet I'm not SETTING the selectedIndex there, so it still seems macabre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I just did this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9)
  {
      tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
  else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
  {
      tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

it'll toggle back and forth just fine.  Without that `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`, however, it exhibited the behavior you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem in the past, and the problem persisted even after removing suspect code from the SelectedIndexChanged() event. I then used a different techniques that worked much better. Instead of using the form KeyDown event, I overrode the form ProcessCmdKey event as follow:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  if (keyData == Keys.F9)
  {
    this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
    return true;    
  }
  else if (keyData == Keys.F10)
  {
    this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```